# Network interfaces not recognized after instrallation

Tags: networking, drivers

I have a new installation of Ubuntu 18.0.4 LTS with kernel only (no DE,Window Manager and other stuff that ships with the installer.It was from a live installer. Kernel : 5.4.0.40,generic. It does not recognize any network interfaces:

1. Wired Realtek
2. USB wifi adapter realtek.

3.Android tethered by USB.

The installer works with 1 and 3. In the chroot environment it shows 1 and 3 .

I have installed the drivers for 2nd interface which works in another Ubuntu installation and arch but not here. It seems to be generic issue. iw dev gives a funny n118402 command not found, ifconfig -a shows lo as the only network interface

lshw and lspcii lists both 1 and 3 . In the chroot environment i did install most of the other things like dhcpcd, net tools and some more basic things to see what was going on. I also did a system upgrade (or is it something wrong?) . Nothing seems to resolve the problem. In chroot the wired interface shows as enps30.Tried to force the interface with dhcpcd , also dhclient after putting an entry in etc/network/interfaces.

lsusb log : http://ix.io/2rd7
lspci log : http://ix.io/2rd9
lshw network log : http://ix.io/2rda

Nothing seems to work> looked around in the forum and google but doesnt work for me. And it seems like my effort to start building Ubuntu from scratch like Arch is failing miserably.Pls help if possible.

Comment: Do you mean the base command line system? I don't think it was ever possible to have a kernel only installation.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `lsusb` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Hi Chillimadded, Also added lspci,lshw for network.In lshw you will see the network device on the motherboard listed.Thanks

Comment: In your `lsusb`, I don't see the USB wireless. Please try again.

Comment: Also, pkease let us see: `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`

Comment: @hilli : There is nothing in the netplan yaml. 01-netcfg.yaml. I removed the usb when taking lsusb.That is a little complicated as the kernel driver doesnt work i have to build a third party driver and then configure.It works with Ubuntu as i have another Ubuntu installation which uses it.For now wired internet connection or andorid tethered USB connection will do.For that usb the build and dkms installation went without errors but modprobe for that driver returns "unknown symbol in module or unknown parameter".

Comment: dmesg log : http://ix.io/2rdw
lots of errors on apparmor

Comment: suggest that we get the ethernet working first. Later, let's address the wireless, if needed, in a new question. In the dmesg you linked, there is no mention of enp3s0. Does it appear if you do: `sudo modprobe r8169` or is some informative error thrown? `dmesg | grep r81` I see NetworkManager mentioned. Is it installed and running? `ps aux | grep etwork` The only thing I see related to apparmor are audits, not errors. These are harmeless and expected.

Comment: Agree,thats hy i left out the adapter from lsusb and mentioned in the comment.modprobe tells men no driver has been loaded,nothing else.Network Manager is running.enp3s0 is the interface name i get when in the chroot env.Just a wild try really,no logic.Any thoughts where to go from here.thanks a ton chilli

Comment: It worked with Ubuntu 20.0.4 , kernel 5.4.20 Generic.Atleast in theory the minimal installation works.There could be some problems down the line as it is made more of a real desktop .Thanks chilli for all yout help.

Comment: I ask again: In the dmesg you linked, there is no mention of enp3s0. Does it appear if you do: `sudo modprobe r8169` or is some informative error thrown? `dmesg | grep r81` We need to see some clues.

Comment: i replied to your enp3s0 in my earlier comment.there was nothing in the dmesg grep.and modprobe told me that no driver was loaded, just this much , which i posted in my earlier comment also. with sudo does not make any difference.the emp3s0 was a wild guess that i mentioned in the earlier comment also

Comment: Very puzzling. Does the ethernet adapter even show up in: `lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A3` I'm not sure how to configure a network connection for a non-existant device. "modprobe told me that no driver was loaded" I don't understand. I have never seen that exact response. Please try again and tell me the precise reply. Please explain further the "chroot env"; what is that?

Comment: I have uninstalled 18.0.4 and put in 20 LTS which works so unfortunately cannot get the exact message.The real problem was that no network interfaces were detected which i have not encountered before. chroot : boot from installation media,mount the installed root to /mnt of install media,bind proc,run,sys,dev,etc/esolv.conf of install nedia to /mnt on which installation's root is mounted. chroot to /mnt .do iw dev or ip link show it lists the ethernet interface,ping google it works.much like what arch-chroot does.